# Fonts with different design sizes

Tags: fonts, pdftex, lmodern

What I like about computer modern and latin modern is, that they have different design sizes. But as https://www.typografie.info/3/topic/22238-ist-die-computer-modern-wirklich-zu-d%C3%BCnn/ shows, lm and other cm-based vector fonts are too thin. Searching for other fonts with different design sizes, I only found EB Garamond http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/design.html, that will provide different design sizes in future. Are there other free vectorfonts with various design sizes for use with pdflatex?

Comment: Coelacanth has optical sizes, but the support files for pdftex seem not to implement them.  Some of the Impallari fonts are getting display fonts to accompany their text fonts, but again, unless you use xetex or luatex, you need support files.